# In Redis, how many HSET keys's keys is too many?

Tags: redis

I've carefully read https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization but I'm still confused. Basically, it says to cap the number of keys in each hash map (`HSET`). But what about the *number of keys* in **each** HSET.

If I have 1,000,000 keys for a certain prefix. Each one with a unique value. Suppose they're integer looking like `"12345689"`. If I "shard" the keys by taking the first two characters (e.g. `"12"`) and the remainder as the "sub key" (e.g. `"3456789"`), then for each hash I'm going to have 1,000,000 / 100 = 10,000 keys each (theoretically). Is that too many?

My (default) config is:

```
redis-store:6379> config get hash-*
1) "hash-max-ziplist-entries"
2) "512"
3) "hash-max-ziplist-value"
4) "64"
```

So, if I shard up each 1,000,000 keys per prefix, I'll have **less than 512**. Actually, I'll have 100 (e.g. `"12"` or `"99"`). But what about within each one? There'll theoretically be 10,000 keys each. Does that mean I break the limit and can't benefit from the space optimization that hash maps offer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use such formula to calculate `HASH` internal data overhead for each key:

3 * next_power(n) * size_of(pointer)

There `n` is number of keys in your `HASH`. I think you are using x64 version of `Redis` so size_of(pointer) is 8. So for each 10,000 keys in your `HASH` your would have at least 240,000 bytes of overhead.

**UPDATED**

Please keep in mind `hash-max-ziplist-entries` is **not the silver bullet**. Please look at article here [Under the hood of Rdis #2](http://redisplanet.com/redis/under-the-hood-of-redis-hash-part-2-and-list/) — ziplist could be calculated as 21 * n and in same time: saving up to х10 RAM you got the write speed subsidence up to 30 times and up to 100 times in reading. So with total amount with 1,000,000 entries in HASH you could catch the critical breakdown with perfomance

You can read more about Redis `HASH` internals [Under the hood of Redis #1](http://redisplanet.com/redis/under-the-hood-of-redis-hash-part-1/).

Comment: I tried to read that article but it was very hard to follow. Also, memory allocation for hash maps difference based on `hash-max-ziplist-entries` and it makes me believe there are two distinct ways to estimate the hashes' size. One when there are few keys and one when there's tonnes of them.

Comment: `hash-max-ziplist-entries` is not the silver bullet actualy. Here is also seconds part of that article here http://redisplanet.com/redis/under-the-hood-of-redis-hash-part-2-and-list/ and ziplist could be calculated as 21 * n. And yes, saving up to х10 RAM you got the write speed subsidence up to 30 times and up to 100 times in reading. So with total amount with 1,000,000 entries in HASH you could catch the critical breakdown with perfomance.

Answer (score 1):

After some extensive research I've finally understood how `hash-max-ziplist-entries` works.
https://www.peterbe.com/plog/understanding-redis-hash-max-ziplist-entries

Basically, it's just 1 hash map or if you need to break it up into multiple hash maps if within you need to store more keys than `hash-max-ziplist-entries` is set to.